# Why do I get the error 'could not find file 'C\Users\daylo\Onedrive\Desktop\VisualStudio\Total Sales\Total Sales\bin\Debug\Sales/txt'

Tags: c#

The problem for a class asks to create an application to that reads numbers from a file to an array and calculates the total of the arrays values. But upon running the program I receive this error:

> could not find file 'C\Users\daylo\Onedrive\Desktop\VisualStudio\Total Sales\Total Sales\bin\Debug\Sales/txt'.

I've tried copying and pasting the actual text file into the Program.cs but the same error appears. I figure the issue is due to the location of the file but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it efficiently.

Here's the code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calcTotalBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("Sales.txt");
            double[] numbers = new double[allLines.Length];
            int counter = 0;
            double sum = 0;

            foreach (string value in allLines)
            {
                numbers[counter] = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                sum += numbers[counter];
                outPutListBox.Items.Add(numbers[counter]);
                counter++;
            }

            outPutListBox.Items.Add("\nTotal: " + sum.ToString("n"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: You are trying to read the file from the _current_ directory. In a Visual Studio debug session this current directory is the folder where the sources of your project  are stored plus the bin\debug subfolder. So your sales.txt is expected to be in that folder. It is not there

Comment: Are you sure thats the exact error message it seems to have no : and that last / should be a dot... where exactly is your Sales.txt file - as  it would need to be in th eworking directory...

Comment: If the file is included in the project, you have to set the "copy to output directory" property..

Comment: Sorry. That is exactly what is says: Could not find file 'C: \Users\daylo\Onedrive\Desktop\VisualStudio\Total Sales\Total Sales\bin\Debug\Sales.txt'.

Comment: Seemed to do the trick Steve. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.ReadAllLines("Sales.txt");
```

means to read the file in the current working directory. This is a terrible practice as you can only guarantee the current working directory if you explicitly change to it. As a best practice, always provide a full path and filename.